# Access the rows of a model B through a list of foreign keys of B

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have 2 models `A` & `B` in django, A stores a list of foreign keys to B in a `JSONField`. In the template, how do I retrieve the `B` instances from the `B` foreign keys stored in `A`?

`models.py`

```
class B(models.Model):
    someField = models.CharField(max_length = 128)

class A(models.Model):
    # e.g. contains [1, 5, 3, 6, 2]:
    foreignKeysOfB = models.JSONField(null = True)
```

`views.py`

```
def myView(request):
    a = A.objects.all()
    b = B.objects.all()
    context = {
        'a':a,
        'b':b,
    }

    template = loader.get_template('my_template.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

`my_template.html`

```
{% for my_a in a %}
    {% for foreignKeyOfB in my_a.foreignKeysOfB %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ do something to get the B out of its foreign key}}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the recommended way of doing this is to define a `ManyToMany` relation between `A` and `B`. Your current method won't enforce referential integrity (e.g. if you delete a `B` instance it won't be deleted from all `A` instances that refer to it). If you are able to change the database schema, and don't *have to* use a `JSONField` I suggest you to do that instead.

That being said, you can easily implement it by adding a helper method to class `A`:

```py
class A(models.Model):
    # e.g. contains [1, 5, 3, 6, 2]:
    foreignKeysOfB = models.JSONField(null = True)

    def get_b_instances(self):
        return B.objects.filter(pk__in=self.foreignKeysOfB)
```

Then you can simply do:

```html
{% for my_b in my_a.get_b_instances %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ my_b.someField }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```